# PHP display picture from folder if name matches product id

Tags: php, image

I am building a catalog function on my website - I want images to be displayed alongside application name and prices. The pictures are to be called from the folder depending on the ApplicationID found. The image name matches the ApplicationID stored in my database.
However when running my code I get the following error: 
`Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/accountname/public_html/search.php on line 47 (being where I call the image).`
Any advice?

```
if(!$start)
        $start=0; 
        $getquery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ApplicationID, ApplicationName, ApplicationDescription, App_cost FROM apps WHERE ApplicationName LIKE '%$search%' OR ApplicationDescription LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT $start, $per_page;");


    while($row = $getquery->fetch_object()){
        $_GET['search']=$_POST['search'];
        echo "<div class=\"col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4\">";
        echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">';           
        echo"<div id='product'><a href='appproduct.php?id=$row[1]'><img src='product_images/$row[1].jpg' alt='Product picture'/>";
        echo '<h2>'.$row->ApplicationName.'</h2>';
        if($row->App_cost=="0.00"){ 
            echo '<p>Free</p>';
        }else{
           echo '<p>'.$row->App_cost.'</p>';
        }
        echo '<button class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="'.$row->ApplicationID.'" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
        echo '</form></div>';
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the line of the error

```
echo"<div id='product'>      
<a href='appproduct.php?id=$row[1]'>
  <img src='product_images/$row[1].jpg' alt='Product picture'/>";
```

You are fetching data as object and using as array resulting error

Replace this with the DB field name

```
$row[1]
```

to

```
$row->colname_for_image
```

Answer (score 0):

$row is an object, but you are trying to use it as an array : `$row[1]`.

If your image matches your application id, you should use that code instead :

```
echo '<div id="product"><a href="'appproduct.php?id=$row->ApplicationID.'"><img src="product_images/'.$row->ApplicationID.'.jpg" alt="Product picture" />';
```